# Power shell SendKeys right Ctrl or numlock Enter

Tags: powershell

I am making a powershell script to automate a task in an internal system at work. I use `SendKeys` to interact with the window but I have to use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the right side of the keyboard or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button on the numlock pad to continue in the program.

I have tried `SendKeys('+')` and `SendKeys('{enter}')` but neither work.

I have searched everywhere but I can't seem to find the commands for right <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, is this even possible?

Comment: The code for `CTRL` is `^`

Comment: Yes but it is the ''wrong'' Ctrl, but thanks